# How can i deserialize an string array to class[]?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

My ajax posts the following array to the controller

```
{"checkedValues":["{ \"o\": 1, \"v\":1}","{ \"o\": 1, \"v\":2}"]}
```

Controller reads the data as an array of string

```
public IActionResult Filter([FromBody] Rootobject checkedValues = null)
{

}
```

where

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] checkedValues { get; set; }
}
```

How can i deserialize the data to an array of

```
public class Filter
{
    public int o { get; set; }
    public int v { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following, with no success

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Filter[] checkedValues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Fix your JavaScript so it sends something reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before: JSON within JSON. It's usually a bug.

As a workaround, you need to double deserialize:

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public string[] checkedValues { get; set; }
}
public class Filter
{
    public int o { get; set; }
    public int v { get; set; }
}
var values = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json)
    .checkedValues
    .Select(JsonConvert<Filter>)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this only with [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var reult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Filter>>(checkedValues.checkedValues);
```

Finally:

```
public IActionResult Filter([FromBody] Rootobject checkedValues = null)
{
  var reult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Filter>>(checkedValues.checkedValues);
}
```